# How to achieve different template function behavior based on template type?

Tags: typescript

I have a remote service which returns JSON containing objects or arrays of objects. Sometimes, when there's one object in the array, the service returns an object rather than array containing one object. There's a function implementing calls to the service:

```ts
export async function ApiCall<T>(funcName : string, args? : ArgList) : Promise<T> {
  var callPromise : Promise<T>;
  //...implementation
  return callPromise;
}
// usage:
ApiCall<MyType>("foo").then((myTypeObj) => {var x = myTypeObj.myField; /*...*/}); //1
ApiCall<MyType[]>("bar").then((array) => { for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) /*...*/  }); //2
```

I want to introduce a patch in this function so that usage remains unchanged - the call to "bar" does not have to know the result of API call may be a single `MyType` object. However, I don't see how to obtain compiled code that does different things in case `1` and in case `2`.

I would think writing two different versions of `ApiCall` and making compiler choose which one to call would work since it has all relevant information in a point of a call but it seems that function overloading in TypeScript is too limited for that.

Forcing all callers to pass an additional flag works, but the solution is ugly and will become worse if further patches like this are needed.

Is there any trick in TypeScript similar to C++ template specialization and/or some other way to solve the problem described? To reiterate, I want a function-like invocation `ApiCall` to do something like

```ts
return callPromise.then((result) => {return Array.isArray(result) ? result : [result];});
```

*if and only if* `T` is an array.

Comment: This is *intentionally* completely impossible. TypeScript is meant to add a type system to describe, not *alter*, JavaScript behavior. [The type system is **erased**](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types). Allowing the behavior of code to depend on a TypeScript generic type parameter `T` (conventionally TS has *generics*, not *templates*) would violate that, so it's explicitly [non-goal #5 of TS](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a, if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz One possible solution would be to write something that compiles into different functions: `callSyntax<MyType>` -> `callImplSingular`, `callSyntax<MyType[]>` -> `callImplArray` as some user-implemented syntax sugar, with no further runtime checks. As things stand, I feel ~encouraged~ forced to pass additional runtime description of `MyType` for the function to work properly, seemingly contrary to the language intent.

Comment: Hmm, you didn't get my point. Non-goal #5, as linked above, explicitly says that TS is not intended to "emit different code based on the results of the type system" which is exactly what it would mean for `callSyntax<T>` to "compile into different functions" depending on `T`. TypeScript (largely) should be valid JS after *erasing* the type system. It is erased, not evaluated, to get JS.  So `callSyntax<T>(bar)` becomes `callSyntax(bar)`  *no matter what*. You are encouraged to do whatever you would have to do in JavaScript to make it work. Do you understand now? Or is there still a disconnect?

Comment: If I understand it right, type system has a constraint "if we were to replace all types in a correct program with `any`, the program should still remain correct and still compile into the same JS" which is stronger than "types may not affect the compiled program execution" I initially assumed. In that case, yes, I see better what I can and can't do, thank you for the help.

Comment: The former is implied by the latter. If you can change `callSyntax<string>()` to `callSyntax<string[]>()` and the program runs differently, then types are certainly affecting the compiled program execution. Indeed the only way for anything in TS to affect compiled program execution is if it compiles to different JS. You seem to think you can envision some situation where types *do not* affect the compiled program execution, but in which replacing the types with `any` *does* change the compiled JS, but that's inconsistent.

Comment: I believe the former to be a stronger statement. If, say, `foo<T>` were to compile into `foo_1`, `foo<T[]>` into `foo_2`, calls `foo<MyType>(0)` and `foo<MyType[]>(0)` into `foo_1(0)` and `foo_2(0)` respectively then compilation would still erase type system in a sense that no runtime type information influences execution of the compiled program. My mistake was understanding "type erasure" in a too weak sense.

Comment: If I wrote `foo<SomeType>(0)`, the compiler would need to know if `SomeType` is a subtype of `Array` to figure out how to compile it. So `SomeType` needs to be evaluated, and then the output of the compiler depends on it. The fact that `foo_1` and `foo_2` appear in the compiled code anywhere is evidence that the type system was consulted to determine the runtime behavior. I think we must both be looking at the same facts and coming to different conclusions, or there's some semantic mismatch where I say "type" and you are thinking of something different? Anyway I'll write an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is intentionally not possible in TypeScript.  [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) (what you're calling "templates", which isn't the conventional term, largely because it implies the sort of compile-time rewriting you're envisioning), along with the rest of the static type system, are completely [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types) upon compilation.  Literally erased. So, by necessity, A function call in TypeScript of the form `apiCall<T>("foo")`  will be compiled into JavaScript of the form `apiCall("foo")`.  That means `apiCall<MyType>("foo")` and `apiCall<MyType[]>("foo")` will both be compiled to the same JavaScript no matter what, so your patch will have nothing upon which to act.

---

With a few exceptions from the early days of the language ([`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) being a big one), TypeScript isn't meant to *add* anything to JavaScript. It's supposed to merely *describe* what happens in JavaScript to make it easier to catch mistakes for the developer.  Thus it is an explicit [Non-Goal of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (see #5) to "emit different code based on the results of the type system".  If the compiler had to look at `apiCall<X>("foo")` and evaluate `X` to see if it's an array or not (maybe `type X = string[]` is somewhere in the code? Or maybe `X` is a generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `any[]`?) in order to determine what the generated JavaScript would be, then it would be in violation of that rule.

So writing TypeScript code is just like writing JavaScript code, except there's a type checker you can communicate with to help keep track of what you're doing.  When you want something to happen at runtime, you will need to write that JavaScript code to do it. So you would have to either write two functions yourself and call them as needed:

```
declare function apiCallArray<T extends any[]>(x: string): Promise<T>
declare function apiCallNonArray<T>(x: string): Promise<T>
```

Or have a single function which takes an extra parameter so that the JavaScript could delegate to the proper version:

```
declare function apiCall<T extends any[]>(arrayVersion: true, x: string): Promise<T>
declare function apiCall<T>(arrayVersion: false, x: string): Promise<T>
```

Or any other approach as long as it's encoded explicitly in the unerased part of the TypeScript code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygAcsBhKCCAOTwEEYYoBPAHgBUA+ACgA8AueAM4YYWVAHMAlPwAKMHAFssAkG3YAoUJFgIU6bHgLEyFOgxat4IbhhCpgAgqkYBtALpc+g4aMky5i5VU1DXBoOCQ0TFx8IlJyCDZLa1t7Rxd3TlgzADUQGAFo-mFkEAAaeE8hEXEpeFkFJRUOEK1w3SiDWOMEjkz6Jlz8wqRyZXLK7xq-BsDmoA)